# Best practice in MySql query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables **master_category**, **category_group** and **articles** as follows
1) **master_category**

```
cat_id             cat_name
------------------------------
1                   Movies
2                   Hollywood
3                   Bollywood
4                   Hollywood Actress
5                   Hollywood Actors
6                   Mobiles
7                   Sony
8                   Apple
9                   LG
10                  Sony Accessories
```

---

1) **category_group**

```
   id             Main_Group         Sub_Group
--------------------------------------------------
   1                  1                  2
   2                  1                  3
   3                  2                  4
   4                  2                  5
   5                  6                  7
   6                  6                  8
   7                  6                  9
   8                  7                  10      
 --------------------------------------------------
```

2) **articles**

```
  id                    title                    description
----------------------------------------------------------------
  1                   sample title                some description
```

Table record goes like this, when i click movies i need to get articles contain word 'movies', 'Hollywood' , 'Bollywood' ,'Hollywood Actress', 'Hollywood Actor' etc ie(  sub group and sub of sub groups etc)

I have done like this

```
SELECT names.* FROM master_category mc LEFT JOIN category_group sc #level1
ON sc.main_group = mc.cat_id LEFT JOIN category_group sc2 #level2
ON sc2.main_group = sc.sub_group LEFT JOIN master_category names
ON sc.sub_group = names.cat_id OR sc2.sub_group = names.cat_id
where mc.cat_name = 'movies' order by names.cat_id;
```

from this query i can get cat_name

**$result** is the array we get from that query result

```
$i=0;
foreach($result as $row)
{
  if($i!=0) { $query_condition.= "or "; } 
  $query_condition.= " title like '%".$row['cat_name']."%' or description like '%".$row['cat_name']."%'";
}
```

this get result like

```
  $query_condition = " title like '%Movies%' or description like '%Movies%' or title like '%Bollywood%' or description like '%Bollywood%' or title like '%Hollywood%' or description like '%Hollywood%' or title like '%Hollywood Actress%' or description like '%Hollywood Actress%' or title like '%Hollywood Actor%' or description like '%Hollywood Actor%'
```

then i wrote final query as follows

```
     select * from articles where $query_condition
```

is this a best practice?  if we have more category time to get final result will increase. is there any other best method to get fast result? please advice me

Comment: Best practise would be to use prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: I don't know how to do that please help me

Comment: Start here, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php or http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php depending on your driver.

Comment: is it useful to get result fast?

Comment: Is your question about performance or security? You currently are open to SQL injections with this code, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Second_order_SQL_injection.

Comment: ok, thanks, but need performance too

Comment: What are your performance requirements? How many requests per second do you expect to handle, and what is your system's current request latency?

Comment: if category and sub category have more than 500. to get a result i need to loop 500times. it is time consuming... is there any method to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you with how to query the DB, but you will need to work on its performance

```
SELECT DISTINCT    
           a.title,
           a.description
FROM       articles a
           INNER JOIN
           (
              SELECT (@clicked_cat_id := cat_id) cat_id,
                     cat_name
              FROM   master_category
              WHERE  Upper(cat_name) = Upper(@clicked_cat_name := "Movies")
              UNION
              SELECT     b.cat_id,
                         b.cat_name
              FROM       master_category b
                         INNER JOIN category_group c
                           ON b.cat_id = c.sub_group
              WHERE      c.main_group = @clicked_cat_id ) c
WHERE      a.title LIKE concat('%',c.cat_name,'%')
```